# Qmake 5.3: define global variable

Tags: qt, qmake

For Qmake 4, I basically followed [this guide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir) to define some `top_srcdir` variable globally for all contained project files.

Now, I want to make my Qmake files also Qmake 5 compatible. It doesn't really work yet. The guide also tells me to create a file `.qmake.conf` with the content:

```
top_srcdir=$$PWD
top_builddir=$$shadowed($$PWD)
```

But it just seems to ignore that file. (Via Qt Creator, as a shadowed build, if that matters.)

If I specify the same in the root project file, it is not exported to any other project.

So, how can I export the variable such that it is available in all subprojects? Or how can I declare it globally for all projects?

Answer (score 1):

There are fundamental differences between Qt 4 and Qt 5 that won't allow you to do that.

The best solution in your case is using a `.pri` file and `include()` it from your subdirs' `.pro` files.

<sub>And: in Qt 5, you should be using `top_builddir=$$shadowed($$PWD)` in your `.qmake.conf`, and not what you typed. In Qt 4, you should place a file called `.qmake.cache` inside your build dir, a bit complicated to do.</sub>

Comment: Like what differences? I'm checking for Qmake 5 now [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948091/qmake-how-to-check-for-qmake-version), and my `.qmake.conf` basically does the same as my `.qmake.cache.in` does for Qmake 4. And it seems to work mostly fine so far.

Comment: Well, you said that you wanted to make them "compatible", the problem is that there's no way as the system has changed. This kind of trickeries are undocumented and unsupported...