# Qmake: how to check for Qmake version

Tags: qmake

I want to write some Qmake project files which are both compatible with Qmake 4 and Qmake 5.

There are subtle differences where I need to check if I it uses Qmake 4. How can I do such a check?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by QMake 5 and QMake 4.  QMake and Qt versions are not the same.  The "--version" reported by QMake that comes with _Qt_ 5.3 is "QMake version 3.0."  QMake that is bundled with _Qt_ 4.8.3 is is "QMake version 2.01a."

Comment: @jwernerny: Ah, thanks for the clarification. With "QMake 4", I mean the QMake version which comes with Qt 4, and with "QMake 5", I mean the QMake version which comes with Qt 5. I thought that for example, that `.qmake.conf` support was introduced by QMake in Qt 5. Or does it make more sense to check for QMake version 3.0 then? Anyway, how would I do that?

Comment: I would use the `QMAKE_VERSION` variable and test 3.x vs. 4.x on that, but I have not worked out the specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Qt version in pro file:

```
equals(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): # do something for Qmake 4
equals(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): # do something for Qmake 5
```